# Why do I need a resistor across VCC in this circuit?

Tags: raspberry-pi, led-strip

I'm newer to electronics and am currently working on a project using a raspberry pi and a set of neopixels (WS2812) leds. I finally decided to get everything running off the same 5v power supply but was getting strange results almost like a pin was floating. After poking around with a multimeter I noticed that measuring voltage in one spot fixed the issue, so I added a resistor and my circuit works, only problem is I have no idea why it is working...

The resistor I added was between vcc in and the vcc pin on my 74ahct125 (logic shifter 3.3v to 5v). Any idea on why this is needed? I've modified the breadboard the tutorial I was following with my changes (running the pi off the same 5v and the resistor).

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Vcc was tied directly to the IC Vcc pin before and you inserted the resistor in series, or there was no connection to Vcc?  If it's the latter, then it didn't work because the chip had no power (and you should just connect it directly without the resistor).  The Vcc pin needs to be supplied with power for the buffers to work.

Comment: You do need power for a device.  Look at pinout for the 74ahct125.

Comment: Before I inserted the resistor the Vcc was tied directly to the Vcc in pin on the logic shifter. I then inserted the resistor in series.

Comment: The device is designed for operation with a power supply range of **4.5V to 5.5V**.

Comment: The 74ahct125? It can operate at up to 7v, but either way the supply I was using is putting out between 4.8-5v depending on load.

Comment: Picture of your actual bread board setup?

Comment: Breadboard connections are notoriously unlreliable. If the vcc wire wasn't making contact, and you moved it to a different hole, or the resistor lead is slightly larger than the wire, then it's possible that the disturbance fixed the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried moving the wire around to different holes or even bridging directly to the pin and nothing changed. Here's my actual breadboard both in the original (sporadically working) layout and the layout with a resistor that caused things to work properly. http://imgur.com/a/z71i1   2 notes: 1) The black box at the bottom is the Pi, the two wires leading off are soldered to the usb power pins, not fed from the pi itself. 2) The circuit in the background wasn't there originally and didn't have any effect on the problem I'm having.